# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList availableList = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0;i<vehicleList.size();i++)
    {
      Vehicle v = (Vehicle) vehicleList.get(i);
      if(v.isAvailable())
         availableList.add(v);
    }

    System.out.println("Option 5.Rent A Vehicle");
    listCustomers(customerList);//displays Customers

    System.out.print("Enter S/No of customer:");
    int c1 = input.nextInt();//user input for S/No of customer

    while(c1 > customerList.size() || c1 < 1)//checks if S/No is valid
    {
    System.out.println("Invalid option! please re-enter S/No of customer");
    c1 = input.nextInt();//prompt user to re-enter S/No of customer
    }

    Customer c = (Customer) customerList.get(c1-1); //creates customer object
    listavailableVehicles(availableList);//displays vehicles

    System.out.print("Enter S/No of Vehicle        :");
    int ve= input.nextInt();//user input for S/No of vehicle
    Vehicle v = (Vehicle) availableList.get(ve-1);//creates vehicle object

    while(ve > availableList.size() || (!v.isAvailable()))//check if S/No is valid
    {
    System.out.println("Invalid option! please re-enter S/No of of vehicle");
    ve = input.nextInt();//prompt user to re-enter S/No of vehicle
    v = (Vehicle) vehicleList.get(ve-1);//creates vehicle object
    }
```

I am having an error here. 
while(ve > availableList.size() || (!v.isAvailable())) 
I mean it can compile, but for validation, it gives me an error. The availableList contains 10 vehicles. When i input 0 or 11 vehicles, it gives me an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 10. According to my while statement, i dont think there is anything wrong. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this? thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific ? which line is it? anyway, if there is an Exception thrown, there is something wrong. Possibly you are going until 'i == size' or something similar, and forgot that Java has indices starting at 0.

Comment: Java arrays are 0-based, so 10 elements mean that you can access the last element at array[9].

Comment: Add stacktrace and makr the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: You're requesting `ve` and use it directly without checking its value. Not good.

Comment: I know. The program works fine other than this error. The vehicle list will be displayed with vehicles 1 - 10. When i press 1 - 10 it works fine, but i am doing validation to make it such that when the user enters a number below 1 or after 10, they will have to re enter the number. The validation line is at the btm.

Comment: Your validation makes no sense to me. You're using `ve` directly after the input request and then you're checking if the input was valid. This won't prevent `IndexOutOfBoundsException`s.

Comment: what should i do to change it in simple beginner terms? i am new to java

Comment: @Brandon 1. request input from the user; 2. check if the value is not too large (`! index  => list.size()`) or too small (`! index < 0`); 3. then use it to retrieve an element from the list: `list.get(index);`. You've currently switched 2 and 3.

Comment: Can you show me in code form? i dont understand..

Comment: Use sberezins first code. If you have a problem with that code, then update your question and include the new code and a problem description (add this under the current question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code
replace your code after

`int ve= input.nextInt();//user input for S/No of vehicle` this line with below code

```
 Vehicle v=null;
 if(ve > availableList.size() || ve <= 0){
     while(ve > availableList.size() || (!v.isAvailable()))//check if S/No is valid
     {
        System.out.println("Invalid option! please re-enter S/No of of vehicle");
        ve = input.nextInt();//prompt user to re-enter S/No of vehicle

        if(ve <= availableList.size() && ve > 0) {
          v = (Vehicle) vehicleList.get(ve-1);//creates vehicle object
          break;
         }

     }
 }
 else
 {
       v = (Vehicle) availableList.get(ve-1);//creates vehicle object
 }
```

Comment: Its working for numbers above 10! how do i make inputs 0 and below show the same error message?

Comment: if you are giving 0 as input than you should write vehicleList.get(ve) not vehicleList.get(ve-1) and update           && ve > 0 with && ve >= 0

Comment: @Brandon change `while(ve > availableList.size() || (!v.isAvailable()))` to `while(ve > availableList.size() || ve < 0 || (!v.isAvailable()))`

Comment: 0 is not input. 0 is an error the user will input so i dont think i can change ve-1 to ve

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at VehicleRental.makeRental(VehicleRental.java:359)
 at VehicleRental.main(VehicleRental.java:48)   got an error while input is 0.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you have ArrayList of length 10 then valid indexes are from 0 to 9.

So you should check size of your ArrayList beforehand like this:

```
if(i >= 0 && i < vehicleList.size()){
   vehicleList.get(i);
   ...
} else {
   ...
}
```

**or** use try-catch like this:

```
try {
    vehicleList.get(i);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // you can log exception here
}
```

Comment: ... - just other actions you need